# Getting the message before the referenced message - discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have two messages in a discord channel:

**message 1**

**message 2** (reference)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message():
    if message.author.id == 555955826880413696:
        embeds = message.embeds
        for embed in embeds:
            dict = embed.to_dict()
            if dict.get("description").startswith("xxx"):
                target = message.id 
                # I got the message I want, now I want to get the message above it
                ...
                await message.channel.send(message_above_it)
```

and my target is to get the content of message 1 right above message 2, how can I do so in discord.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely want to use the `history()` function in the channel and set the before parameter to get all the message send before your message.
So an example would be:

```py
messages = await message.channel.history(limit=10, before=target).flatten()
found_message=messages[0] # Use the 0 to get the first message found
```